# vue.js code is not working in django project

Tags: html, vue.js

below is my code by using vue.js I have written thee code and here my problem is while i am running this code in notepad++ it is working fine but while i am working with django project at pycharm it is not giving any output. As you can I have interpolated message, so its is giving me the output at notepad++ but not in pycharm with django project if anyone have an idea about this please help me struggling a lot for this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
<% message %>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
message: 'Hello world!',
delimiters: ["<%","%>"]
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delimiters` shouldn't be inside `data`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
<% message %>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
message: 'Hello world!',
},
delimiters: ["<%","%>"]
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html i am facing this error while i am running the code

Comment: @sonu wait that's must not be an error that's must be a notification though but still if you want to disable that you can just add this line at the end of the script ``Vue.config.productionTip = false``